# How to unit test cascade delete entities in Entity Framework ?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How can we test the cascade deleting of entities in Entity Framework?

I have two entities[Parent and Child] and I'm using FakeDbset(In memory collection), if I delete parent then their all child get deleted from the database in case of the cascade, then how this same scenario get tested in FakeDbSet ?

I know cascade is database feature, is **Effort** work in this situation?

Comment: Don't unit test this. If the constraint is removed from the database (for whatever reason, maybe a faulty upgrade script) your unit tests will never notice. This is a case for integration tests or end-to-end tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3924

This helped me, you need to have the child in your context, so you will need to .Include the child using Eager Loading.

This following code is from the link I attached:

```
[Fact]
void test_written_in_notepad()
{
    List<int> childIds;
    using (var context = CreateInMemoryContext())
    {
        var parent = context.Parents.Include(p => p.Children).FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == 1);
        childIds = p.Children.Select(c => c.Id).ToList();
        context.Remove(parent);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    using (var context = CreateInMemoryContext())
    {
        Assert.Empty(context.Children.Where(c => childIds.Contains(c.Id));
    }
}
```